# Using a character pointer array to store multiple char arrays

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, strtok

I have the following code in which I'm reading lines from a file and want to save them using a character pointer array. As I'm using one buffer inside my file read loop all my pointers in the character array end up pointing towards the last line read from file as the last line is the one that is currently held in the buffer when the loop terminates. How can I store them such that each pointer in the character array points to different char arrays in the order they were read.

```
int num_clients_to_start = 0;
char *token1, *token2,  *str;
FILE* fp;
char bufr[256];
char testchar[255] = {}; 
char *start_client[10];

while(fgets(bufr, 256, fp) != NULL){

    if(bufr[0] == '#'|| bufr[0] == '\n')
    continue;

    str = bufr;

    token2 = "";  /* initializing an empty token 2 */
        for(str = bufr;  ;str = NULL){
    token1 = strtok(str, " ");
    if(strcmp(token2, "client_name") == 0){
        sprintf(testchar,"%s", token1);
            start_client[num_clients_to_start] = testchar;
        num_clients_to_start++;
    }                   

    token2 = token1;

    if(str == NULL){
            break;
    }
  }//end of for loop

}//end of while loop

printf("client1 = %s client2 = %s client3 = %s",start_client[0],start_client[1],start_client[2]);
```

My input file is the following:

```
client_name abc
client_name def
client_name xyz
```

And print statement outputs:

```
client1 = xyz
client2 = xyz
client3 = xyz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the same pointer to all entries in the `start_client` array. The array `testchar` will get different contents, but the pointer to it will always be the same. You might want to make `start_client` an array of arrays of `char`, and copy the string instead.

Like

```
char start_client[10][256];
```

And

```
strcpy(start_client[num_clients_to_start++], token1);
```

Comment: sorry, I think i must have missed the assignment to token1 while copying my code. Have made the edit

Comment: Yes thats the case, the pointer to `testchar` is the same hence  at the end all prints statements are printing the same thing. Thats what I want to know, how to avoid this?

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar Yes. Either that or use `strdup` (but then you have to remember to `free` the pointers when you're done with them).

Comment: Right, so in your solution above basically `start_client[0]` will then be the first array, `start_client[1]` be the second and so on?

Comment: Thanks, that added to my knowledge. I'm a little confused now if I should accept your answer or @AlterMann's. Both have covered the same solution.

Comment: Zahaib, if you are in doubt, always accept the oldest answer (Joachim)

Answer (score 3):

Note that `start_client[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` are all pointers to the last string (readed by `fgets`)

Use [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/strdup.html) in order to allocate them:

```
start_client[num_clients_to_start] = strdup(testchar);
```

As `strdup` can be an external identifier, use a prototype

```
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *s);
```

And don't forget to `free()` at the end